# mysql new row, at insert it gets 1+ value of last record

Tags: mysql

table

```
id name num
11 abc  2
12 def  3
13 ghi  4
14 jkl  5
```

how to make the **num** column if i insert **new row** with out having input data automatically the 
**num** colum read last row column num and add 1 to the value of the last column and insert the result of (last row num value + 1) on the new row num column.
note: the prevous row column num will not get any effect.

for example now i go from backend database and manualy i change the value of num and set

```
   15 jkk  1
```

now the new row should get the value of 2 and it happens only in insert not update or delete.

```
 16 mno  2
```

if it's possible with mysql trigger how i can set the trigger that get effect from the prevous row means the last row been effected.

how to manage it on database level. regards

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, maybe you can try this

INSERT INTO table (num) SELECT (num + 1) FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1

Comment: yes this is correct but her every time i have to insert i want to make it automatic when i insert new row(the new num column) data should calculat(last num column value + 1) and add it to new column as on the new colum which the fields are(id, name, num) the value i will provide will be only(1, thename) not the num the num should get from the prevous one.